# The greatest common divisor of $(O_n, T_n+2)$ where $O_n$ and $T_n$ are the oblong and triangular numbers respectively.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Suppose that $T_n$ is odd. Can we find infinitely many $n$ such that $(O_n, T_n+2)=1$? Is it trivial and obvious? My hunch based on some hand calculations is to look at $n$ congruent to $0$ or $2$ modulo $4$.

Comment: The triangular numbers $T_n$ are widely familiar, so perhaps need not be defined. But the oblong numbers $O_n$ are less familiar.

Comment: $O_n = n (n+1) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that by $T_n$ is meant $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

We want to show that if $T_n$ is odd, then the gcd of $T_n+2$ and $O_n$ is equal to $1$.

Equivalently, by multiplying through by $2$, we want to show that if $T_n$ is odd then the gcd of $n(n+1)+4$ and $2n(n+1)$ is equal to $2$. 
Note that
$$\gcd(2n(n+1),n(n+1)+4)=\gcd(n(n+1)+4,-8)$$
(we used one step of the Euclidean Algorithm).

Since $n(n+1)/2$ is odd, the greatest power of $2$ that divides $n(n+1)+4$ is $2$, and we are finished.